# new "Send To" button and icon in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed this button in my Google Chrome shortcut menu. It also occasionally shows up in the right end of the Google Chrome "address input bar".

What does it do? (I don't have a computer called `DESKTOP-NIO94F0`).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently logged in with your google account on that PC. The 'Send to' actions allows to send the current tab to another device (e.g. you find a cool website on the phone and want to open it on the pc without having to copy the url and sent it to yourself/retype the url or creating a temporary bookmark).

If you do not reconize the PC I would suggest you to go to you google account -> connected devices and logout of everything, changing your password and using 2FA.